# Print Row and Column Header if column/row is not NaN Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

It's a weird question - but can y'all think of a good way to just print the rows or a list of the rows and their corresponding column headers if the dataframe cell is not NaN?

Imagine a dataframe like this:

```
     col1   col2    col3    col4
1    1      NaN     2       NaN
2    NaN    NaN     1       2
3    2      NaN     NaN     1
```

Result should look something like this:

```
1    [col1: 1, col3: 2]
2    [col3: 1, col4: 2]
3    [col1: 2, col4: 1]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something like: `df.apply(lambda s: s[s.notnull()].to_dict(), axis=1)` ? https://akuiper.com/console/mOeBwjFoGW-s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transpose the dataframe, and for each row, drop NaNs and convert to dict:

```
out = df.T.apply(lambda x: dict(x.dropna().astype(int)))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
1    {'col1': 1, 'col3': 2}
2    {'col3': 1, 'col4': 2}
3    {'col1': 2, 'col4': 1}
dtype: object
```

Comment: Transpose is computationally expensive. If you have to handle it at dataframe level please use stack

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `stack`

```
df.stack().reset_index(level=0).groupby('level_0')[0].agg(dict)
Out[184]: 
level_0
1    {'col1': 1.0, 'col3': 2.0}
2    {'col3': 1.0, 'col4': 2.0}
3    {'col1': 2.0, 'col4': 1.0}
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

combine agg(dict) and list comprehension

```
d = [{k:v for k, v in x.items() if v == v } for x in df.agg(dict,1)]

[{'col1': 1.0, 'col3': 2.0},
 {'col3': 1.0, 'col4': 2.0},
 {'col1': 2.0, 'col4': 1.0}]
```